# Latex. Limit bibliography to 10 authors. After that write et al

Tags: bibliographies

I would like to print my bibliography in this format:

```
Saiki RK, Scharf S, Faloona F, Mullis KB, Horn GT, Erlich HA, Arnheim N. 1985. 
Enzymatic amplification of X-globin genomic sequences and restriction site 
analysis for diagnosis of sickle cell anemia. Science 230: 1350-1354.
```

I am using these settings:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}  
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{pdflscape} % to rotate tables
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}      
\geometry{letterpaper}                          
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{authblk} % to add affiliations
\bibliographystyle{apsrev}
\usepackage{float}  % to place figures at specific locations
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\bibliography{mybib-blx2.bib}

\end{document}
```

If there are more than 10 authors, add "et al" after the 10th author name. Is there any easy way to do this, without having to create a custom bibliography style by modifying the .bst file?

This is the format of the articles used in mybib-blx2.bib:

```
@article{Piras:2012aa,
    Abstract = {....},
    Author = {Piras, Ignazio Stefano and De Montis, Antonella and Cal{\`o}, 
Carla Maria and Marini, Monica and Atzori, Manuela and Corrias, Laura and 
Sazzini, Marco and Boattini, Alessio and Vona, Giuseppe and Contu, Licinio},
    Date-Added = {2018-01-30 22:29:25 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2018-01-30 22:29:25 +0000},
    Doi = {10.1038/ejhg.2012.65},
    Journal = {Eur J Hum Genet},
    Journal-Full = {European journal of human genetics : EJHG},
    Mesh = {Genome, Human; Genome-Wide Association Study; Haplotypes; 
Homozygote; Humans; Italy; Polymorphism, Single Nucleotide; Population 
Groups; Selection, Genetic},
    Month = {Nov},
    Number = {11},
    Pages = {1155-61},
    Pmc = {PMC3476709},
    Pmid = {22535185},
    Pst = {ppublish},
    Title = {Genome-wide scan with nearly 700,000 SNPs in two Sardinian sub- 
    populations suggests some regions as candidate targets for positive 
    selection},
    Volume = {20},
    Year = {2012},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/ejhg.2012.65}}
```

Comment: Without telling us how you are producing your bibliography, no. With `biblatex` it's trivial.

Comment: Please provide a suitable `.bib` entry. Most of us do not have `mybib-blx2.bib`. Why do you have two `\bibliographystyle` lines?

Comment: `booktabs` and `multirow` don't add symbols. They are used in formatting tables.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @AlanMunn. I just provided an example of a .bib entry. Is this OK?

Comment: It doesn't have more than 10 authors ....

Comment: I'm confused. If you add one more author to this `.bib` item, it will appear with 'et al.' So the `apsrev` bibliography style already does what you want, i.e., up to 10 authors spelled out, and for > 10, spell out the first 10 and et al for the rest. Although none of the formatting of the names and initials match the format in your example.

Comment: @AlanMunn, I do not have much experience with Latex. I posted this because I don't know how to do it. Yes, my .bib is formatted in this way. Yes, apsrev prints the name of <11 authors and adds et al, but I cannot figure out how to print my bibliography in the format specified  in my post: authors, year, title, journal, etc. So far you have told me how I have done things wrong, but you have not told me how to do it right. By reading my post, do you know how to solve this?. Yes (@cfr), my .bib example does not have more than 10 authors, but does it matter?. It is just an example.

Comment: It's not so much that you've done something wrong, but your question appears to be asking about the number of authors, but what you really want is to change the *formatting* of the names. We were confused because your question title doesn't reflect that. It will be simplest to find a different bibliography style that matches your formatting better.

Comment: Thank you @AlanMunn, in the first statement of my post I specified the format I wish. I have looked a lot over the internet to find this format but I have not found it.

Comment: Unfortunately bibliography formatting is not so simple, and you can't define a style based only on the format of an article. How are other elements to be formatted, e..g. articles in edited books, books, etc.? Does the `apsrev` style work as you want for all of these *except* the name/initials formatting? If so it is possible to make a modified version of `apsrev`, but if not, then this is a much more complicated question, and you would be better off using `custombib` to create your own `.bst` file or use `biblatex`.

Comment: Hi @AlanMunn, I created a custom bib using custombib and it works very nice. However, I would like to cite my references in the main text as (Smith et al. 2017) and when compiling the tex file I get "Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations". I replaced apsrev by custom bib style "mybib". Do you have any suggestion?. Thank you.

Comment: Did you delete your `.aux` files and recompile?